# How .xib is actually loaded during runtime?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to know how an .xib is loaded into the memory during runtime or whenever we run the application.

Comment: Are you looking for general understanding, or are you trying to use this knowledge to solve a particular problem?

Comment: Read through [Resource programming guide: The Nib Object Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/loadingresources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW18)

Comment: One side point, this will help you  *XIB is kinda source-code, which gets converted into nib, and this nib is loaded via initWithNibName method. NSCoding, NSKeyedUnarchiver are used to decode and load it into memory and allows you to show it.*

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how an .xib is loaded into the memory during runtime or whenever we run the application.

Then you should read up on `NSCoding`, `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, and object serialization in general. Notice that the objects you're likely to store in a nib file all implement `NSCoding`, and `UIView` in particular has `-initWithCoder:` as one of it's two designated initializers. The `UIView` class reference says this:

> `initWithCoder:` - Implement this method if you load your view from an
>   Interface Builder nib file and your view requires custom
>   initialization.

Basically, Xcode's UI editor (often known as Interface Builder) writes a set of objects into an archive. When you load a .xib in your application, the archive is read into memory and deserialized into the object graph that you specified.

Comment: can you give sm overview on this

Comment: I *could*, but I'd just be repeating what's already in the documentation for the classes I mentioned. If you've read them already and still don't understand, please be more specific about what you're asking.